# typescript. defining an addition to prototype

Tags: typescript

One of the external library I use add a `format` method to string prototype.but, I cannot use it.

```
error TS2094: The property 'format' does not exist on value of type 'string'.
```

I defined an interface for this type.

```
 interface String {
        format : (any) => string;
    }
```

and tried like

```
var test:String =  "test".format({});
```

which gives error

```
error TS2012: Cannot convert 'string' to 'String':
```

if I define the `format` method myself like

```
String.prototype.format = function (d:any) : string {
...
}
```

the error disappears. But, I don't want to define it myself, it is given by the external library. tried casting with `<String>`. didn't work. How to do this.

--

### Edit:

@basarath showed how it works. But, this is the way I was using it. It doesn't work, if I define the interface within the module
[see](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=//%20interface%20String%20%7B%0D%0A//%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20format%3a%28any%29%20=%3E%20string;%0D%0A//%7D%0D%0Amodule%20test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20String%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20format%3a%28any%29%20=%3E%20string;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Clazz%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor%28%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.fn%28%29;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fn%28%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20url%3astring%20=%20%22test%22.format%28%7B%7D%29;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D)

```
// interface String {
//        format:(any) => string;
//}
module test {
    interface String {
        format:(any) => string;
    }
    class Clazz {        
        constructor() {
            this.fn();
        }

        fn() {
            var url:string = "test".format({});
        }
    }
}
```

is it because the changes to string prototype would not be visible outside the module?

Comment: If you use the implicit return of type `string` from the call to `format` or declare the return type: `var test:string =...`, I don't see an error.

Comment: You've changed it to be an interface called `String` in a module `test` which would be different from the global type now.

Comment: thanks. I am new to typescript, and didn't know String is a type defined as builtin. Now, it make sense. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should just work

```
interface String {
    format : (any) => string;
}

var test:string =  "test".format({});
```

And [indeed it does](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=%20%20%20%20interface%20String%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09format%20%3A%20(any)%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20test%3Astring%20%3D%20%20%22test%22.format(%7B%7D)%3B)

Note that `String` is not the same as `string` :

```
var strObject = new String('foo');
var strValue = 'foo';

strValue = strObject; // Error
```

And the reason is the way *javascript* works. One is an object, the other is not:

[image]

Comment: thanks. how does this work.where does it say string (native type) implements "String".

Comment: ok, I saw the section 3.2.3 The String Type in the spec. I didn't know `String` was more than a random name. :-)

Comment: Also see : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/810 what I asked a long time ago :)